# Privacy usage description error despite being in info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist, cncontactstore

I'm getting this error in Xcode despite the fact that I have added a description string for NSContactsUsageDescription in info.plist. It's happening in the simulator and on iPad & iPhone.

```
[access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSContactsUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
```

I have tried cleaning, rebuilding, deleting the app from the device, restarting Xcode. Deleting from info.plist and adding again. I've also checked the source code for info.plist to see that the key has been added correctly.

I keep getting this error!

Comment: Add NSContactsUsageDescription Key and Respective contact usage description in your info.plist file. Because iOS doesn't want to allowed privacy content without user's permission.

Comment: Currently there are key name will be "Privacy - Contacts Usage Description".

Comment: You must add value with your key, only key will not work

Comment: I've added "NSContactsUsageDescription". It changes automatically to "Privacy - Contacts Usage Description". When you look at the source, it is there as <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>